# npm run build не создает проект

Tags: vue.js

Есть небольшой проект на vue,

Установил командой:

```
 npm install -g vue-cli
```

Потом

```
vue init webpack-simple
```

При окончании его в директории проекта в терминале пишу команду

```
npm run build
```

Создаются только *build.js.map* и *build.js*.

*Вопрос:*
 где собственно сам проект как в документации?

Comment: Сделайте вначале `npm install vue`, потом `npm run build`.

Comment: Kosta B, а ничего что он уже был проинсталирован а потом еще и запущен npm run dev?

Comment: Возможно в вашем вопросе не хватает информации. Дополните, что вы уже сделали, что работает. Какие ошибки выдает, если выдает и т.д.

Comment: Kosta B. все как в описании документации написано npm install -g vue-cli, потом vue init webpack-simple, после запустил проект на http://localhost:8080, создал небольшой проект и потом npm run build и ничего

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли сделать команду:

```
npm install
```

Перейдите в директорию проекта

```
cd your-project
npm install
npm run dev
npm run build
```

Для того, чтобы увидеть результат можно поднять любой простой сервер:

- `php -S localhost:8080`
- `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`
- `python3 -m http.server`

Comment: дважды проделал заново эти шаги, все равно создает два файла build.js.map и build.js

Comment: @аноним дополнил. это шаблон для быстрого прототипирования (не для продакшен).

Comment: Kosta B. меня конечный результат интересует, то что можно на хост загрузить

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что вы выбрали пресет [webpack-simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) в котором нет стандартного функционала который предлагает `Vue-cli`, а более урезанный.

Попробуйте создать проект с помощью команды:

```
vue create <название проекта>
```

Эта команда создаст стандартный `Vue` проект с необходимыми директориями и файлами, которые после сборки вы сможете загрузить на любой хостинг.

Более подробно про `Vue-Cli` вы сможете посмотреть в [документации](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/installation.html)

Comment: Можно не поднимать старые ответы @ДухСообщества ? Все равно никто не выберет правильного ответа и это просто бесмысленно.